# drag and drop row from datagridview to TextBox

Tags: c#

Text is not transferred. The code is not mine, it originally worked with a `listBox`.
I can move individual cells, but I need to move a row here. The data source is selected in a `DataGridview` in the form.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.AllowDrop = true;
    dataGridView1.AllowDrop = true;
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(dataGridView1.SelectedRows, DragDropEffects.Move);
}


private void textBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e){
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection)))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
}


private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection rows = (DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection));

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
    {
        textBox1.Text = row.Cell[1].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include more information about what is not working and what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add and modify the code in `textBox1_DragDrop` as follows.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        textBox1.Text += cell.Value.ToString() + " ";
    }
}
```

Test result,

[image]

**Update**

```
private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            textBox1.Text += dataGridView1.Rows[cell.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value.ToString() + " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An empty string is transferred

Comment: I have attached the result gif. Everything works fine in my test.

Comment: Yes, only added the above code. Did you subscribe to all the 3 events?

Comment: Yes. It is strange why so.

Comment: It works, but  need to select a row. Can I get rid of it?

Comment: According to the code you provided, yes, you need to select the row, rather than the cell. Do you want to select any cell and all the cells in the row will be dragged to textbox?

Comment: @OIlUnion I have updated the answer. Hope it can work in your project.